# jQuery form plugin - no response, no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using this [plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form).

I've rewritten my code to work with the example:

```
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var queryString = $.param(formData); 

    return true; 
} 

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 

    $(".afterSend").removeClass("preloader");               
    $(".afterSend").empty().append(responseText);

} 

    $(function() {
        $('form.wycena').bind("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();     

            if($('.formBox').hasClass('lightBox')) {

                $(".afterSend").empty().addClass("preloader");

                $("form.wycena").ajaxForm({
                    target:        '.afterSend',
                    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
                    success:       showResponse

                });
            }

            else {
                /* verify before sending */
                toggleLightBox(true);
            }

        });
    });
```

My code works, but `ajaxForm` and its callback functions (`showRequest`, `showRespons`) seems to do nothing at all. It is supposed to run the script defined in form's action field and show response in the `.afterSend` div, but I get nothing. Not even a single error in console.

Comment: Probably you have a server side error? try to catch onError on you ajaxForm. Callback function to be invoked upon error.

Comment: Noo, it worked before I used that plugin. But I can't go back, since I need this plugin to send form's uploaded files via AJAX.

Comment: if you want help, try to use error callback. It's the only way to kwno if you are having some server side error's or anything.

Comment: USe firefox or chrome console to see if the request got response from the server too.

Comment: I see what I did wrong - I should use `ajaxSubmit`, not `ajaxForm`.